# Programmatically have Client application list a WCF service's Endpoints created during runtime using a URL (like WCF Test Client does)

Tags: c#, wcf

Maybe I'm not searching with the right terms because this seems pretty simple. I'm just looking for a way to list the endpoints of a WCF service that has it's endpoints created during runtime the same way WCF Test Client Does.

1. **Specify URL**

[image: Add URL]

2. **Get MetaData and Endpoints**

[image]

**This is how I add the endpoints during runtime**

```
string SetInstrumentsURL = serviceUrl + "SetInstruments/";
string SetInstrumentsPipe = "net.pipe://localhost/TestService/SetInstruments/";
ServiceHost SetInstrumentsHost = null;
var SetInstruments = InstrumentLoader.Factory.GetIEnumerableOf<ISetInstrument>();
if (SetInstruments.Count() > 0)
{
    Uri SetInstrumentsURI = new Uri(SetInstrumentsURL);
    Uri SetInstrumentsPipedURI = new Uri(SetInstrumentsPipe);
    NetTcpBinding netTcpBindingSetInstruments = new NetTcpBinding();
    NetNamedPipeBinding NamedPipeBindingSetInstruments = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
    SetInstrumentsHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TeraSetInstrumentService), new Uri[] { SetInstrumentsURI, SetInstrumentsPipedURI });
    ServiceMetadataBehavior SetInstrumentServiceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    SetInstrumentsHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(SetInstrumentServiceMetadataBehavior);
    SetInstrumentsHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");
    SetInstrumentsHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), "mex");
    foreach (var setter in SetInstruments)
    {
        SetInstrumentsHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISetInstrumentService), netTcpBindingSetInstruments, SetInstrumentsURL + setter.Name).Name = "Set_" + setter.Name.Replace(" ", "_");
        SetInstrumentsHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISetInstrumentService), NamedPipeBindingSetInstruments, SetInstrumentsPipe + setter.Name).Name = "Set_" + setter.Name.Replace(" ", "_");
    }
    SetInstrumentsHost.Open();
}
```

What functions can I use from the client side to access those same endpoints as WCF Test Client? I know how to connect to those endpoints if I already have the Endpoint's URL but I would like to have a list of the endpoints so I can create a drop down list choose from that changes depending on what host you connect to.

Adding a service reference through Visual Studio doesn't list all of the endpoints because the are not created yet. Is the a library I can use to get them at run time like WCF Test Client does.

Comment: As far as I know, we could use ChannelFactory to create the communication channel manually by specifying the endpoint address, then invoke the service.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory     https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/channel-factory-in-wcf/

Comment: we could get these endpoints by using SVCUTIL.exe tool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Comment: I forgot to add that I am trying to get these endpoints programmatically, so if there was a C# library to use that would be best. I feel like the service model library would have a function to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that we have the service metadata URI, we could use MetadataExchangeClientMode and MetadataResolver class which is provided in the System.ServiceModel.Description namespace to retrieve and process the metadata.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-metadataresolver-to-obtain-binding-metadata-dynamically
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-metadataexchangeclient-to-retrieve-metadata

I have made a simple example, wish it is useful to you.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:3336/mex");
            MetadataExchangeClient client = new MetadataExchangeClient(uri, MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange);
            MetadataSet metadata = client.GetMetadata();
            WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metadata);
            ServiceEndpointCollection endpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();

            //ServiceEndpointCollection endpoints = MetadataResolver.Resolve(typeof(IService), uri, MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange);
            foreach (var item in endpoints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Address.Uri);
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello();
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was pretty easy to do, I just needed to use the **MetadataExchangeClient** to get the config. In the code all I had to do to get the MetaData Xml was this:

```
var meta = new System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClient(new Uri("net.tcp://10.0.2.124:9000/TeraService/SetInstruments/mex"), System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange);
var data = meta.GetMetadata();
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("xmlfile.xml");
x.Serialize(writer, data);
writer.Close();
```

I posted my answer in the wrong place. But Abraham Qian has a more elegant solution that I will test now.